# Getting jQuery jPages plugin to work with EmberJS and Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to get jPages to work with EmberJS. It appears the jPages tries to bind to elements that don't load in time because of the Ajax call. Has anybody gotten this to work? Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/8hDRJ/33/

**Handlebars**:

```html
<div class="songs">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Songs.songsView}}
        <div id="song-items">
        {{#each Songs.songsController}}
            <div class="song">
                <p>{{artist}}</p>                  
            </div>
        {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="pagination"></div>
    {{/view}}
    </script>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```js
Songs.songsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addSong: function(song) {
        this.pushObject(song);
    },
    getSongs: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://test.com/getSongs?callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data){
              var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
              for (var i=0; i<obj.songs.length; i++) {
                self.addSong( Songs.song.create( obj.songs[i]) );    
              }
            }
        });
    }
});

Songs.songsView= Em.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
      $('.pagination').jPages({
        containerID: "song-items",
        perPage: 2
      });  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the song elements are not yet in the DOM when you instantiate the `jPages` plugin. That's why it's not working.

My solution is to create a property `loaded` on the controller. When it's set to true, the view knows that the content is loaded and it can instantiate `jPages`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/dpqCn/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="song" >
    {{content.artist}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
Songs.songsController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    getSongs: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            success: function(data) {
                var songs = data.songs.forEach(function(song){
                    return Songs.Song.create(song);
                });

                // add all songs at once
                self.pushObjects(songs);

                // set the loaded property to true to indicate that the content is filled
                self.set('loaded', true);
            }
        });
    }
});

Songs.SongsView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: 'songsView paginationView'.w(),
    loadedBinding: 'controller.loaded',

    // invoked when the loaded property of the controller is changed
    _loadedChanged: function() {
        if (this.get('loaded')) {
            // get the songsView instance
            var songsView = this.get('songsView');

            // call jPages plugin on next run loop
            // when content has been filled and elements have been inserted to DOM
            Ember.run.next(this, function() {
                this.$('.holder').jPages({
                    containerID: songsView.get('elementId')
                });
            });
        }
    }.observes('loaded'),

    paginationView: Ember.View.create({
        classNames: 'holder'.w()
    }),

    songsView: Ember.CollectionView.create({
        contentBinding: 'parentView.controller.content',
        tagName: 'ul',
        itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
            templateName: 'song'
        })
    })
});
```

---

*Another note*: your naming conventions are not Ember conform. See a [blog post](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html) by the Emberist. So classes are `UpperCase` and properties and instances are `lowerCase`.